# Django DB Model, Create two identical tables, one inheriting from the other

Tags: django, django-models

I have a requirement where I would like to have identical tables in Django. For example MyTableCurrent and MyTableArchive.

The tables should be identical except of the class/table name and the foreign key references.

Is there a way to basically maintain the schema on MyTableCurrent, then under MyTableArchive, I inherit from the base class of MyTableCurrent but override just the foreign key fields to match the corresponding Archive table?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution I was looking for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

```
class ServiceProviderBase(models.Model):
    sp_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    isEnterprise = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    cluster = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class ServiceProviderCurrent(ServiceProviderBase):
    pass


class ServiceProviderArchive(ServiceProviderBase):
    pass


class GroupBase(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    grp_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=False)
    userLimit = models.IntegerField()
    organizationType = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class GroupCurrent(GroupBase):
    organizationId = models.ForeignKey('sandbox.ServiceProviderCurrent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class GroupArchive(GroupBase):
    organizationId = models.ForeignKey('sandbox.ServiceProviderArchive', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table and  other two table inheritenced from this table.Sample:

```
class BaseMedal(models.Model):
  field_one = models.ForeignKey(TableName,...)
  field_two = models.ForeignKey(AnotherTableName,...)

class ModelOne(BaseModal)
  field = models.TextField(...)

class ModelTwo(BaseModel)
  field = models.TextField(...)
```

this way foreignkey fields are same for ModelOne and ModelTwo.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [Proxy Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). For example:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    # your common fields


class Current(BaseModel):
     class Meta:
         proxy=True

     def some_current_model_method(self):
         # specific method for this class

class Archive(BaseModel):
     class Meta:
         proxy=True

     def some_archive_model_method(self):
         # specific method for this class
```

#### Update

Usage:

```
archive1 = Archive.objects.create(title="Archive 1")
archive2 = Archive.objects.create(title="Archive 2")
current1 = Current.objects.create(title="Current 1")
current2 = Current.objects.create(title="Current 2")


archives = Archive.objects.all().count()  # will print 4
currents = Current.objects.all().count()  # will print 4
base = BaseModel.objects.all().count()  # print 4


Archive.objects.get(title="Archive 1")  # will work
Archive.objects.get(title="Current 1")  # will work

Current.objects.get(title="Archive 1")  # will work
Current.objects.get(title="Current 1")  # will work

BaseModel.objects.get(title="Archive 1")  # will work
BaseModel.objects.get(title="Current 1")  # will work

BaseModel.objects.create(title="BaseModel")
Archive.objects.get(title="BaseModel")  # will work
Current.objects.get(title="BaseModel")  # will work
```

Comment: Looking proxy docs, it has the following comment. 'The MyPerson class operates on the same database table as its parent Person class. In particular, any new instances of Person will also be accessible through MyPerson, and vice-versa'. If my current and archive classes have two different values for the same table field, but in current or archive, how does this work?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but I still don't think this will work for my intended purpose. For example, on the first four lines, imagine that archive1 and current1 but have title 'My Title'. The primary key is most likely going to be the same value for both current and archive tables. I need a solution that will allow me to have identical values in both tables. The main part i am trying to avoid is maintaining the schema on both models, the only differences i care about are the table name and that the foreign key matches the appropriate table.

Comment: @JeffA sorry, I did not test my code properly. I have gave wrong example for in my last answer. Please see my updated answer.